# Mass Delete Files in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Instead of having to ctrl-click on each individual file in a folder to delete. I would like to select a group of files and delete. Is this possible?

Comment: The FileBrowser plugin is useful for that kind of thing: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileBrowser

Answer (score 0):

Multiple selection is available with `ctrl` and/or `shift` keys + click (default Windows behavior). Then right click -> "Delete" item deletes selected files.